# Task (appointment) scheduling library in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

Is there any good task scheduling library in C#/.NET ?

I don't mean task in the sense of 'print job', I mean task in the business sense, like you schedule your tasks in Outlook.

Preferably with overview and calendar, preferably ASP.NET.

Comment: Do you wish the library do to the scheduling or to display the schedule?  i.e. are you looking for automatic scheduling, or UI?

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: Good question. Both I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) and it works very well, you can make the scheduling as fine grained as you need it. Its open source and very well written. The library doesnt have the UI stuff, but only takes care of the actual scheduling, should be easy to implement though, the hard part is the scheduling.

Comment: I *think* Quartz.net schedules "jobs" as in processing that needs to be run on a computer.  And I *think* the question is asking about "apointments", as in a doctor apointment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASPxScheduler](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Scheduler/) from Devexpress.